# Handling infix operator

Tags: parsing, haskell, parsec

I'm trying to parse a simple language defined as follows:

```hs
import Data.Functor.Identity
import Data.Text (Text)
import qualified Data.Text as T
import Text.Parsec
import qualified Text.Parsec.Expr as Expr

data G
  = Low Int
  | Up Int
  | And G G
  | Or G G
  deriving stock (Eq, Show)

parseIt :: Text -> Either ParseError G
parseIt = parse defP "parseIt"

type Parser = Parsec Text ()

defP :: Parser G
defP = goP <* eof
  where
    goP :: Parser G
    goP = Expr.buildExpressionParser table term
    table :: Expr.OperatorTable Text () Identity G
    table = [[binary And "&&", binary Or "||"]]
    term :: Parser G
    term =
      choice
        [ parens goP,
          unary Up ">",
          unary Low "<"
        ]
    binary :: (G -> G -> G) -> String -> Expr.Operator Text () Identity G
    binary func operator = Expr.Infix (string operator >> return func) Expr.AssocLeft
    unary :: (Int -> G) -> String -> Parser G
    unary mkSpec op = do
      void $ string op
      skipSpaces
      mkSpec <$> numP
    parens = between (symbol "(") (symbol ")")
      where
        symbol name = lexeme (string name)
        lexeme p = do x <- p; skipSpaces; return x
    skipSpaces = skipMany space
    numP :: Parser Int
    numP = do
      xs <- many1 digit
      return $ read xs
```

I have few test cases to exercise it:

```hs
import Control.Monad
import Test.Hspec

main :: IO ()
main = hspec spec

spec :: Spec
spec = do
  describe "should be parsed" $ do
    forM_
      [ (">1", Up 1),
        ("< 42", Low 42),
        (">1 && <42", Up 1 `And` Low 42),
        (">1 || <2 && >5", Up 1 `Or` (Low 2 `And` Up 5)),
        ("((>1 || <2)) && >5", (Up 1 `Or` Low 2) `And` Up 5)
      ]
      $ \(raw, expected :: G) ->
        it (T.unpack raw) $ parseIt raw `shouldBe` Right expected
```

But they fail on binary operators:

```
should be parsed
  >1 [✔]
  < 42 [✔]
  >1 && <42 [✘]
  >1 || <2 && >5 [✘]
  ((>1 || <2)) && >5 [✘]

Failures:

  test/Spec.hs:29:43: 
  1) parseVersionSpec, should be parsed, >1 && <42
       expected: Right (And (Up 1) (Low 42))
        but got: Left "parseIt" (line 1, column 3):
                 unexpected ' '
                 expecting digit, operator or end of input

  To rerun use: --match "/parseVersionSpec/should be parsed/>1 && <42/"

  test/Spec.hs:29:43: 
  2) parseVersionSpec, should be parsed, >1 || <2 && >5
       expected: Right (Or (Up 1) (And (Low 2) (Up 5)))
        but got: Left "parseIt" (line 1, column 3):
                 unexpected ' '
                 expecting digit, operator or end of input

  To rerun use: --match "/parseVersionSpec/should be parsed/>1 || <2 && >5/"

  test/Spec.hs:29:43: 
  3) parseVersionSpec, should be parsed, ((>1 || <2)) && >5
       expected: Right (And (Or (Up 1) (Low 2)) (Up 5))
        but got: Left "parseIt" (line 1, column 5):
                 unexpected " "
                 expecting digit, operator or ")"

  To rerun use: --match "/parseVersionSpec/should be parsed/((>1 || <2)) && >5/"

Randomized with seed 1024517159

Finished in 0.0016 seconds
5 examples, 3 failures
*** Exception: ExitFailure 1
```

I cannot find proper examples, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that, in parsing `">1 && <42"`, `term` parses `">1"`, but leaves a space at the beginning of the remainder of the input stream `" && <42"`, which causes `binary` to fail.

To properly handle whitespace, you should write a set of lexemes that each expect to start parsing at non-whitespace and take responsibility for absorbing any trailing whitespace when finished, and then write the rest of your parser in terms of these lexemes only, without using non-lexeme parsers like `string`.

Move your `lexeme` and `symbol` definitions up to top-level, or at least the level of `defP`'s `where` clause:

```
skipSpaces = skipMany space
lexeme p = do x <- p; skipSpaces; return x
symbol name = lexeme (string name)
```

Define `numP` as a lexeme:

```
numP :: Parser Int
numP = lexeme $ do
  xs <- many1 digit
  return $ read xs
```

and in the rest of your parsers, make use only of the lexeme-level parsers `numP` and `symbol`.

For example, replace `string`/`skipSpaces` in `unary` with `symbol`:

```
unary mkSpec op = do
  void $ symbol op
  mkSpec <$> numP
```

This is a valid lexeme parser, because it parses the lexeme `symbol op` followed by the lexeme `numP`.  Do the same in `binary`:

```
binary :: (G -> G -> G) -> String -> Expr.Operator Text () Identity G
binary func operator = Expr.Infix (symbol operator >> return func) Expr.AssocLeft
```

Also, in your top-most parser `defP`, allow leading whitespace:

```
defP :: Parser G
defP = skipSpaces *> goP <* eof
```

Finally, if you actually want `&&` to have higher precedence than `||`, you need to replace:

```
table = [[binary And "&&", binary Or "||"]]
```

with:

```
table = [[binary And "&&"], [binary Or "||"]]
```

The resulting parser should pass all your tests:

```
defP :: Parser G
defP = skipSpaces *> goP <* eof

  where

    goP :: Parser G
    goP = Expr.buildExpressionParser table term

    table :: Expr.OperatorTable Text () Identity G
    table = [[binary And "&&"], [binary Or "||"]]

    term :: Parser G
    term =
      choice
        [ parens goP,
          unary Up ">",
          unary Low "<"
        ]

    binary :: (G -> G -> G) -> String -> Expr.Operator Text () Identity G
    binary func operator = Expr.Infix (symbol operator >> return func) Expr.AssocLeft

    unary :: (Int -> G) -> String -> Parser G
    unary mkSpec op = do
      void $ symbol op
      mkSpec <$> numP

    parens = between (symbol "(") (symbol ")")

    skipSpaces = skipMany space
    lexeme p = do x <- p; skipSpaces; return x
    symbol name = lexeme (string name)

    numP :: Parser Int
    numP = lexeme $ do
      xs <- many1 digit
      return $ read xs
```

Stylistically, you may also find that switching everything to consistent applicative style makes for a nicer looking parser.  Given everything's in a `where` clause, I might also argue that dropping most of the type signatures would be better.  They don't do much for readability:

```
defP' :: Parser G
defP' = skipSpaces *> goP <* eof

  where

    goP :: Parser G
    goP = Expr.buildExpressionParser table term
      where
        table = [[binary And "&&"], [binary Or "||"]]
        binary func operator = Expr.Infix (func <$ symbol operator) Expr.AssocLeft

    term = parens goP <|> unary Up ">" <|> unary Low "<"
      where unary mkSpec op = mkSpec <$ symbol op <*> numP

    parens = between (symbol "(") (symbol ")")

    numP :: Parser Int
    numP = lexeme (read <$> many1 digit)

    skipSpaces = skipMany space
    lexeme p = p <* skipSpaces
    symbol name = lexeme (string name)
```

Comment: awesome answer! thank you so much. Just a quick question, why should I change `&&` precedence? I just want to allow parenthesis to change associativity.

Comment: In your test case `">1 || <2 && >5"`, it looks like you've assumed that `&&` has higher precedence than `||`. If they have the same precedence (as in your original version of `table`), the operations will associate to the left, and this will parse the same as `"(>1 || <2) && >5"`.